# Content-Type header [text/plain] is not supported

Tags: http, elasticsearch, post, postman

I am trying to understand elasticsearch, so I will use url to create a page where it will have the contents of the raw in postman. My thing is, everytime I send the post request, it does not work. Reading the [Elasticsearch Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types) for `Elasticsearch 7.x` shouldn't this have worked when I created the url `_bulk` for the `_doc`? All I did was start elasticsearch then open up postman, using a post method and then typed a random url and filled some things inside of the raw. Not sure why I am getting 406 not acceptable. Is there something I am doing incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elasticsearch supports JSON format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_content_type_requirements). You need to change from `text` to `json` format in the dropdown

[image]